# Kubernetes jenkins pod template creating pod in wrong namespace

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-jenkins-plugin

We have a jenkins master-slave architecture and using the Kubernetes Jenkins plugin. The podTemplate looks as below

```
podTemplate(label: 'builder-pod', cloud: 'kubernetes', containers: [
        containerTemplate(
                name: 'jnlp',
                image: "${artifact_repo}/jenkins-slave",
                ttyEnabled: true,
                privileged: false,
                alwaysPullImage: false,
                workingDir: '/var/jenkins_home',
                resourceRequestCpu: '1000m',
                resourceRequestMemory: '1Gi',
                resourceLimitMemory: '1.1Gi',
        )
], volumes: [hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run', hostPath: '/var/run')], namespace: 'jenkins') { //podtemplate
    node('builder-pod') {
        container('jnlp') {
```

For whatever reason the builder-pod is being created in `default` namespace instead of the `jenkins` namespace

Any idea what could be wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could always force the namespace by including that in your container definition:

```
containerTemplate(
                name: 'jnlp',
                namespace: 'jenkins',
                image: "${artifact_repo}/jenkins-slave",
                ttyEnabled: true,
                privileged: false,
                alwaysPullImage: false,
                workingDir: '/var/jenkins_home',
                resourceRequestCpu: '1000m',
                resourceRequestMemory: '1Gi',
                resourceLimitMemory: '1.1Gi',
        )
```

As to why it isn't being loaded into the proper namespace, do you have a default kubernetes plugin config setup anywhere? There are settings for both the general namespace target and individual container template namespace targets. If you have neither, the above solution to set the namespace value may be the only way

Answer (score 0):

check the name with:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

And then change the context namespace before deploying your pod

```
kubectl config <NAME> set-context --namespace=jenkins
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your response. This jenkins slave pod is being created by the jenkins master pod - as part of running a job.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on the Jenkins admin interface the Kubernetes plugin configuration, you are able to override some parameters from de UI.